# Is there a way to batch normalize a folder of audio files?

Tags: audio, automation

I have a folder of 2000+ audio files that be to all be normalized to the same level (-14 dB specifically). Is there a script I can write/use in either Python or C# so I don't have to individually edit each one?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This kind of question is generally [not on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on Stack Overflow and should instead be asked on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pydub module to achieve normalization of peak volume with the least amount of code. Install `pydub` using

```sh
pip install pydub
```

By using `os.walk` you can get file names; And by using `endswith` you can check file format.

This code normalizes all audio file in `BASE_PATH` and saves them in `OUTPUT_PATH`.

You have to change `BASE_PATH` and `OUTPUT_PATH` and `AUDIO_FORMAT_LIST` by considering your situation.

```py
from pydub import AudioSegment
import os

BASE_PATH = "your/files/folder/path/"
OUTPUT_PATH = "path/that/you/want/save/new/files/"
AUDIO_FORMAT_LIST = ["mp3", "wav"]  # audio formats you want to change


def match_target_amplitude(sound, target_dBFS):
    change_in_dBFS = target_dBFS - sound.dBFS
    return sound.apply_gain(change_in_dBFS)


filenames = next(
    os.walk(BASE_PATH),
    (None, None, []),
)
for filename in filenames:
    flag = False
    file_audio_format = ""
    for audio_format in AUDIO_FORMAT_LIST:
        if filename.endswith("." + audio_format):
            flag = True
            file_audio_format = audio_format
            break
    if flag:
        sound = AudioSegment.from_file(BASE_PATH + filename, file_audio_format)
        normalized_sound = match_target_amplitude(sound, -14.0)
        normalized_sound.export(
            OUTPUT_PATH + "nomrmalized" + filename, format=file_audio_format
        )
```